# Set shipping address in PayPal Adaptive Payment call

Tags: php, paypal, drupal-7, paypal-adaptive-payments

For a marketplace project, I use the PayPal Adaptive Payment to make parallels payments between the buyer, products salers and the website Paypal account for fees.

In order to apply the Seller Protection, I need the buyer to select a shipping address but I can't find any option to send it.
It seems that I can set the option "requireShippingAddressSelection" to true only with embedded payment flow but is there any way to send a custom address with? And above all, does this option make the payment available for the PP seller protection which is what my client really looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use [SetPaymentOptions](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/SetPaymentOptions_API_Operation/) to include details like shipping address, order items, shipping amount, tax amount, etc.

Your Pay request action will be set to CREATE and then you'll pass that PayKey into SetPaymentOptions to set all of the other details prior to redirecting the user to PayPal to complete the checkout.

Comment: I am doing this and getting successful responses, yet the shipping info still doesn't appear to be being passed in. Are there any other steps I'm missing?

Comment: Are you completing the payment all the way through and then looking at the transaction details in PayPal or are you expecting the details to show up on the PayPal review screen during checkout?  Unfortunately, that won't happen.  It won't show up until the transaction is complete and you look at the transaction details.

Comment: I'm checking the transaction details, but I think the problem may be that I'm using the PayPal ruby gem `paypal-sdk-adaptivepayments` which I'm beginning to think doesn't support sending the shippingAddress in senderOptions :(

Comment: Haha! So I found out that I needed to pass the country in as "US" rather than "United States". No documentation anywhere, just a random guess. Oh PayPal...